# Python package not installable in docker container

Tags: python, docker, pip, cvxopt

I have basic python docker container file like this:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

EXPOSE 8000

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app:app"]
```

I want to run my flask application in a docker container by using this definition file. Locally I can start a new virtual env, install everything via `pip install -r requirements.txt` on python 3.8 and it does not fail.

When building the docker image it fails to install all packages from the requirements.txt. For example [this](https://cvxopt.org/) package fails:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cvxopt==1.2.5.post1
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cvxopt==1.2.5.post1
```

When I comment out the package in the requirements.txt everything seems to work. The package itself claims to be compatible with python >2.7. Same behavior for the package pywin32==228 [here](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looing at the [wheel files in the package](https://pypi.org/project/cvxopt/1.2.5.post1/#files), cvxopt.1.2.5.post1 only contains a build for Windows. For Linux (such as the docker container), you should use cvxopt.1.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the version with 1.2.5 (`pip install cvxopt==1.2.5`)

The latest version `cvxopt 1.2.5.post1` is not compatible with all architectures: https://pypi.org/project/cvxopt/1.2.5.post1/#files

The previous one is compatible with a lot more hardware and should be able to run on your Docker image: https://pypi.org/project/cvxopt/1.2.5/#files

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are totally right. Unfortunately, @Mureinik was a minute earlier and so I accepted his answer.

Comment: Mine was 1 minute earlier ;) But no worries I am just glad your issue is solved